# Rearranging the terms so that the denominator becomes the numerator

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I have the equation
$$ \frac{120}{1 + 3.167 \cdot e^{-0.05t}}  = 60 $$

How do I transform it so that the denominator becomes the numerator? This would make the problem much easier.

Comment: Let me know whether I've edited your equation correctly.  If I have revised this properly, you can write this as $$ \frac{120}{1 + 3.167 \cdot e^{-0.05t}} \  = \ \frac{60}{1} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{120}{60} \  = \ 1 + 3.167 \cdot e^{-0.05t} \ . $$  You can now isolate the exponential term algebraically, then divide out the 3.167 to leave yourself with an "exponential equation" to solve using logarithms.

Answer (score 2):

Multiply both sides by $1 + 3.167e^{-0.05t}$ to get

$$120 = 60 \cdot (1 + 3.167 e^{-0.05t})$$

Divide both sides by $60$ to get

$$2 = 1 + 3.167 e^{-0.05t}$$

So we have

$$\dfrac{1}{3.167} = e^{-0.05t}$$

Now, solve for $t$, using $\ln$.